# How to get a value in textbox after change in dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, textbox, selectionchanged

I have a dropdown and a textbox in html as shown below:

```
<select name="Dur" required class="style4" id="Dur" form="form1">
    <option>Please Select</option>
    <option value="Daily">DAILY</option>
    <option value="Weekly">WEEKLY</option>
    <option value="Monthly">MONTHLY</option>
</select>
<div align="right" class="style2">No Of Installments : </div>
<input name="No_Inst" type="text" class="style4" id="No_Inst" form="form1" size="5"></td>
```

I need to get a value in the textbox to be entered by user if option selected is `Daily` or `Weekly` and the value to be `0` if option selected is `Monthly`.

Need a javascript as I am new.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
document.querySelector('#Dur').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  if (event.currentTarget.value === 'Monthly') {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return document.querySelector('#No_Inst').value;
  }
});
```

Comment: Now this is the script I am using :
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function SelectDur() { 
document.querySelector('#Dur').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  if (event.currentTarget.value === 'Monthly') {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return document.querySelector('#No_Inst').value;
  }
});
}
</script>

But it is still not working. Please help

Comment: Comments are not the correct format for this. Furthermore “it is still not working” does not give me (or anyone else) any context. Are there errors in the console? Did you actually call this new `SelectDur` function you have defined? Have you considered undertaking online education such as [Treehouse](http://teamtreehouse.com/)? (No affiliation).

Answer (score 0):

try as shown below if you are using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
$('.style4').change(function(){
  var a = $(this).val();
    if(a == 'Monthly'){
        $('#No_Inst').val(0)
    }
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/visnupriya/84zd6gf1/

Answer (score 0):

Javascript

```
//Getting a text
document.getElementById('Dur').addEventListener("change",function(){
    return this.options[this.value].innerHTML
});

//Getting the value
document.getElementById('Dur').addEventListener("change",function(){
    return this.options[this.value];
});
```

JQUERY

```
$('#Dur').on("change",funtion(){
      return this.options[this.value].innerHTML
});

 $('#Dur').on("change",funtion(){
      return this.options[this.value];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to use pure javascript, you need to create a javascript function that binds the `<select>` change event, let's say the function name is `bindChangeEvent`, then set the `onload` attribute of `<body>` tag to that function. Your html code should look like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload="bindChangeEvent()">
    <select name="Dur" required class="style4" id="Dur" form="form1">
        <option>Please Select</option>
        <option value="Daily">DAILY</option>
        <option value="Weekly">WEEKLY</option>
        <option value="Monthly">MONTHLY</option>
    </select>
    <div align="right" class="style2">No Of Installments : </div>
    <input name="No_Inst" type="text" class="style4" id="No_Inst" form="form1" size="5">
    <script>
        function bindChangeEvent() {
            document.getElementById("Dur").onchange = function () {
                if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].value == "Daily"
                    || this.options[this.selectedIndex].value == "Weekly") {
                    document.getElementById("No_Inst").value = "";
                }
                else if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].value == "Monthly") {
                    document.getElementById("No_Inst").value = "0";
                }
            };
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fa29jwe5/

Comment: This works fine in jsfiddle but is not running on my .php page. How to call this function please explain as I am a novice/begginner.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Please check the updated answer, I have tested the code and it worked.